# tetrahedrizing a mesh

Tags: mesh, triangulation, tetrahedra

I am looking for an algorithm that receives a 3d surface mesh (i.e comprised of 3d triangles that are a discretization of some manifold) and generates tetrahedra inside the mesh's volume.

i.e, I want the 3d equivalent to this 2d problem: given a closed curve, triangulate it's interior.

I am sorry if this is unclear, it's the best way I could think of explaining it.

For the 2d case there's [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html). For a 3d case I could find none.

Comment: You want to break it up in pieces later? Like in physics simulation? If yes, it seems very interesting! And, oh, I believe plural form is *tetrahedra* (based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron).

Comment: I believe the 2 terms used more frequently are tetrahedralization and 3d triangulation.  Check out this talk for a good overview: http://archive.org/details/lecture_10309

Comment: A quite interesting problem. I even have a hard time coming up with the brute force exhaustive algorithm. Does "for every triangle, pick another vertex in the mesh to add a new tetrahedron (by trying all vertices) that does not intersect a previous one" even work? I think this does not even work in 3d without additional vertices in the general case.

Comment: Is the original mesh convex or arbitrary? Can the tetrahedra in the interior be arbitrary in size, or are there angle / size / volume constraints on them?

Comment: @Mikeb - the mesh is not convex. There are no constraints - I think even state of the art algorithms can give very little guarantees as the ones you mention. 
But I am looking for a package, not a suggested algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [GRUMMP](http://tetra.mech.ubc.ca/GRUMMP/) which seems to answer all the needs mentioned in the question, and more...

Comment: Were you able to download GRUMMP onto a windows computer?

Answer (score 3):

[pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/#volume-meshes-from-surface-meshes) (a project of mine based on [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/)) can do just that.

```
pygalmesh-volume-from-surface elephant.vtu out.vtk --cell-size 1.0 --odt
```

https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/#volume-meshes-from-surface-meshes

[image]

Comment: I am using marching cubes to identify objects. I then create a triangular mesh. I see from your package that it is possible to calculate volume from a surface mesh. I see that your elephant file is in the form '.vtu'. Do I need to convert my mesh into this form? Also, very impressed at your project.

Comment: pygalmesh understands all formats that [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) does -- many.

Comment: Nico, I've been trying to download pygalmesh, but it doesn't see where Eigen\Dense is.. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Schlomer I've done that. I am using a Windows machine. This is very complicated and not working. I do not know how to change the setup.py for pygalmesh. My problem is very similar to https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any experience using GRUMMP, but as far as a 3D version of triangle there is tetgen.  If you know the triangle switches it is built to resemble it.  It also has fairly decent documentation and a python wrapper for it and triangle.

http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/

http://mathema.tician.de/software/meshpy/